# MYSQL Function gets progressively slower

Tags: mysql, performance, function

I created the following function to input records by parsing a string:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS RowPerRow ;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION RowPerRow()
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
BEGIN
    DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0 ;
    DECLARE m INT DEFAULT 0 ;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0 ;
    DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0 ;
    SELECT count(*) FROM Temp0 INTO n ;
    WHILE i < n DO
        SELECT words INTO m FROM Temp0 LIMIT i, 1 ;
        SET j = 1 ;
        WHILE j <= m DO
            INSERT INTO Temp1 SELECT words,id,api,basin,play,drilltype,tradeflag,score,cnf,fracdate,
                fracdateend,state,county,operator,wellname,prodtype,latitude,
                longitude,datum,depth,water,nonwater,surfactant,tradename,TRIM(Split_Str(tradename, ',', j)) AS tradename_c,
                supplier,purpose,ingredients,cas,additive,fluid 
            FROM Temp0 LIMIT i,1 ;
            SET j = j + 1 ;
        END WHILE ;
        SET i = i + 1 ;
    END WHILE ;
    RETURN '' ;
END ;
$$
```

The function gets progressively slower as the number of records increase.

Comment: We'd expect this function to get slower and slower as the number of rows in `temp0` increases. We also expect we might get skipped or duplicated results, especially if someone inserts or deletes rows from Temp0 while this is running. (There's no ORDER BY on the queries, so the order the rows that are returned is not guaranteed. Repeatedly running the same query, with an increasing offset is a very inefficient way to return all the rows in the table. Processing this RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) is going to be slow. **Was there a question?** (or was this just a status report?)

Comment: Agree with the comment made by @spencer7593. Please update the question with more specifics in terms of what you are expecting, or questions you have about optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "What is an example of an alternative way to do this same RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing but which doesn't get progressively slower", I can give an example of what that would look like.

If there's an upper bound (maximum value) for `words`, this same result can be accomplished in a single statement:

```
  INSERT INTO Temp1 
         ( words,  id,  api,  basin,  play,  drilltype,  tradeflag  ,score  ,cnf,  fracdate,  fracdateend,  state,  county,  operator,  wellname,  prodtype,  latitude,  longitude,  datum,  depth,  water,  nonwater,  surfactant,  tradename,  supplier,  purpose,  ingredients,  cas,  additive,  fluid
         , tradename_c )
  SELECT t.words,t.id,t.api,t.basin,t.play,t.drilltype,t.tradeflag,t.score,t.cnf,t.fracdate,t.fracdateend,t.state,t.county,t.operator,t.wellname,t.prodtype,t.latitude,t.longitude,t.datum,t.depth,t.water,t.nonwater,t.surfactant,t.tradename,t.supplier,t.purpose,t.ingredients,t.cas,t.additive,t.fluid
         , TRIM(Split_Str(t.tradename, ',', n.i)) AS tradename_c
    FROM Temp0 t
    JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20) n
      ON n.i <= t.words
```

But here is an example of a procedure that does the equivalent of the original procedure, except that it uses cursor loop instead of repeatedly re-querying the `Temp0` table. Note that the datatypes of the variables (which accept the values from the row returned by fetch) should match or be compatible with the datatype of the corresponding expression in the SELECT list. Here I've declared them all as VARCHAR(100) as a placeholder, these will need to be changed to match the columns from the Temp0 table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION RowPerRow_alt()
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
BEGIN
    -- variables for cursor fetch
    -- the datatype of each variable should match the datatype 
    -- of the expression in SELECT list of the query
    DECLARE v_words        INT;
    DECLARE v_id           VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_api          VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_basin        VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_play         VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_drilltype    VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_tradeflag    VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_score        VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_cnf          VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_fracdate     VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_fracdateend  VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_state        VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_county       VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_operator     VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_wellname     VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_prodtype     VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_latitude     VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_longitude    VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_datum        VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_depth        VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_water        VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_nonwater     VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_surfactant   VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_tradename    VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_supplier     VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_purpose      VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_ingredients  VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_cas          VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_additive     VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_fluid        VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0 ;
    DECLARE v_tradename_c  VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE done TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;

    -- cursor for Temp0
    DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR
      SELECT words,id,api,basin,play,drilltype,tradeflag,score,cnf,fracdate,
             fracdateend,state,county,operator,wellname,prodtype,latitude,
             longitude,datum,depth,water,nonwater,surfactant,tradename,
             supplier,purpose,ingredients,cas,additive,fluid 
        FROM Temp0;
    -- setup NOT FOUND handler    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;  

    OPEN csr;
    rowloop: LOOP
        FETCH csr INTO v_words,v_id,v_api,v_basin,v_play,v_drilltype,v_tradeflag,v_score,v_cnf,v_fracdate,v_fracdateend,v_state,v_county,v_operator,v_wellname,v_prodtype,v_latitude,v_longitude,v_datum,v_depth,v_water,v_nonwater,v_surfactant,v_tradename,v_supplier,v_purpose,v_ingredients,v_cas,v_additive,v_fluid;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE rowloop;
        END IF;
        SET j = 1;
        WHILE j <= v_words DO
            -- split tradename and insert row ti Temp1
            SET v_tradename_c = TRIM(Split_Str(v_tradename, ',', j));
            INSERT INTO Temp1 ( words,  id,  api,  basin,  play,  drilltype,  tradeflag  ,score  ,cnf,  fracdate,  fracdateend,  state,  county,  operator,  wellname,  prodtype,  latitude,  longitude,  datum,  depth,  water,  nonwater,  surfactant,  tradename,  supplier,  purpose,  ingredients,  cas,  additive,  fluid,
              tradename_c )
                     VALUES ( v_words,v_id,v_api,v_basin,v_play,v_drilltype,v_tradeflag,v_score,v_cnf,v_fracdate,v_fracdateend,v_state,v_county,v_operator,v_wellname,v_prodtype,v_latitude,v_longitude,v_datum,v_depth,v_water,v_nonwater,v_surfactant,v_tradename,v_supplier,v_purpose,v_ingredients,v_cas,v_additive,v_fluid,
              v_tradename_c );
            SET j = j + 1 ;
        END WHILE;
    END LOOP rowloop;
    CLOSE csr;
    RETURN '' ;
END$$
```